# No document is generated after project build using DefaultDocumentation

Tags: c#, .net, default-document

I have created fresh project and install Default Document [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DefaultDocumentation) latest package (Version="0.8.2"). Updated the csproj file with following PropertyGroup

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
        <DefaultDocumentationFolder>Documentation\Api</DefaultDocumentationFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="DefaultDocumentation" Version="0.8.2">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

then I build soultion inside Visual Studio (Version 17.8.3) and no document is created. I am expecting .md file at location `BuildLocation\Documentation\Api`. Anything I am missing?

Attached sample project [DefaultDocumentationTest.zip](https://github.com/Doraku/DefaultDocumentation/files/13776153/DefaultDocumentationTest.zip)
Created new  [Issue](https://github.com/Doraku/DefaultDocumentation/issues/153)

Comment: I suspect something broken with version 0.8.2. When I tried with 0.8.1 it worked fine.